# Magento multi store website issue

Tags: php

Friends

I have a website in magento it is multi website and multi store view. it's working fine in live site. but in development site it's not working for all the website.

FOR EXAMPLE In live site website 1. www.example.com 2. www.example1.com 3. www.example2.com

In development site website 1. dev.example.com 2. dev.example1.com 3.dev.example2.com  from this only first one working second and third not working.

Please help me any one

Thanks
Mohan NK

Comment: how it's not working?

Comment: I' dont know i have checked in core_config_data and index.php both are fine.

Comment: because dev.example.com are recognised as **sub-domains** whereas www.example.com is recognised as **domain**. Magento basically has three approaches:
- Domain (e.g. www.store1.com and www.store2.com)
- Subdomain (e.g. store1.mystore.com and store2.mystore.com)
- Folder (e.g. mystore.com/store1/ and mystore.com/store2/)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Admin and check you domains

System > Config> General> Web > secure and unsecure URL base URL for every store.